# Change figure of addLayersControl in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm wondering if there is a way to replace the symbol of  `addLayersControl` in `leaflet` to something else more customized or even a title.

[image]

Comment: To add a title you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072510/r-add-title-to-leaflet-map/49083681#49083681)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do it with r language but with CSS you can overide leaflet style like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/84a0uhL1/

```
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/126/126472.png) !important;
    background-size: 26px;
}
```

You may not need !important tag if you edit the original css. You can also use `:after` property and `content:"Your text"` if you can't use Javascript

Hope it will help you.