# R googleway: add a title on the map?

Tags: r, googleway

Could anyone share an example on how to add a title on the google map?

I tried using add_markers, but those are for particular locations. I searched online for an example but none available.

Looking for something similar to leaflet package function *addControl*.

Comment: "title on the google map" - can you give an example of what you're after?

Comment: Sure. I was looking for similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072510/r-add-title-to-leaflet-map

Comment: You can't do this (yet) in googleway, but I've added it as a [TODO](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/186).