# Set title of leaflet for R web page

Tags: r, leaflet, htmltools

I am using the R leaflet package to generate a [map](https://www.davidmkaplan.fr/davidmkaplan.location_map.html). When the web page is created, the `<title>` element of the web page is set to "leaflet":

```
<title>leaflet</title>
```

I would like to change this to something more informative, but I cannot see a way to do this. I have seen the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072510/r-add-title-to-leaflet-map), but that is to add a title on the map itself. I want to do something different: set the title that is shown at the top of the browser tab.

Is there a simple way to do this using leaflet or htmltools?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution to this issue. The title can be set when the leaflet object is written to a HTML file using either `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` or `mapview::mapshot`:

```
mapshot(x=lf,url="map.html",title="Map title")
```