# Add a title to the Leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping, maps

I have a simple question but still do not know how to find the answer to it. All I need is to add a title to the leaflet map. I do not need it to me on the map, just above it as in a usual ggplot map.

My code is:

```
map <- leaflet(data_counts) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng=data_counts$Long, lat=data_counts$Lat, 
             color="#2c4f54", fillOpacity=0.6,
             stroke = FALSE,
             radius=~sqrt(NumObs)/pi*10,
             label=~paste(data_counts$`Birth place...14`), labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F))
```

I have tried different options but still no success

Comment: Can you show what options you tried and what didn't work please. Anything at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072510/r-add-title-to-leaflet-map useful?

Comment: @user20650 These are exactly the options I have tried and that is not what I want because all of them place the title ON the map and not Above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you already found a solution but you could try this:

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)


tag.map.title <- tags$style(HTML("
.leaflet-control.map-title {
transform: translate(50%,50%);
position: fixed !important;
left: 45%;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 28px;
}
"))

title <- tags$div(
  tag.map.title, HTML("This is the Title")
)

map <- leaflet(data_counts) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng=data_counts$Long, lat=data_counts$Lat, 
             color="#2c4f54", fillOpacity=0.6,
             stroke = FALSE,
             radius=~sqrt(NumObs)/pi*10,
             label=~paste(data_counts$`Birth place...14`), labelOptions = 
labelOptions(noHide = F))  %>%
addControl(title, position = "topleft", className="map-title")
```